# from to date validation in wpnation theme

Tags: validation, date

In my hotel booking website. I have check-in date and is available to choose greater than the check-out date. The below is my code snippet.

```
if ( nationOption.bookingCalendar ) {

    $("#resend-step2 #check-in-date, .step1 #check-in-date, .room-content-description #check-in-date").datepicker({

        dayNames:dayNames,
        dayNamesShort:dayNamesShort,
        dayNamesMin:dayNamesMin,
        monthNames:monthLong,
        monthNamesShort:monthShort,

        dateFormat:dateFormat,

        nextText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>',
        prevText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>',
        minDate: dateToday,
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('resend-datepicker');
        },
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

    $("#resend-step2 #check-out-date, .step1 #check-out-date, .room-content-description #check-out-date").datepicker({

        dayNames:dayNames,
        dayNamesShort:dayNamesShort,
        dayNamesMin:dayNamesMin,
        monthNames:monthLong,
        monthNamesShort:monthShort,

        dateFormat:dateFormat,

        nextText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>',
        prevText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>',
        minDate: dateToday,
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('resend-datepicker');
        },
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

}
```

Anyone help me out to fix this issue.